# Visual Studio 2017: Incompatible VCProjectEngine and EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, envdte

I am currently working on a legacy project that supports multiple VS versions (VS 2008 to VS 2015) and now supporting VS2017, for C++ Applications.
The project itself is in C# (in VS 2015).

In it, I am required to convert an EnvDTE.project into a VCProjectEngine.VCProject.

This conversion is working for other versions, but for VS2017 NULL is returned.

The following is a minimized working code for VS 2015:

```
//Here, EnvDTE and VCProjectEngine provided for VS2015 are used.
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine;
..
..
//Path for a small VS2015 solution file.
String slnPath = @"<**>\Project_2015\Project_2015.sln";
Type EnvDteType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0");

object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(EnvDteType, true);
EnvDTE.DTE DteObject = (EnvDTE.DTE)obj;

EnvDTE.Solution SolutionObject = (EnvDTE.Solution)DteObject.Solution;
SolutionObject.Open(slnPath);

Projects ProjectObjects = SolutionObject.Projects;
foreach (Project project in ProjectObjects)
{
  //vcpro generated successfully.
  VCProject vcpro = project.Object as VCProject;
}
```

However, the same code for VS2017 gets NULL in vcpro.

```
//Here, EnvDTE and VCProjectEngine provided for VS2017 are used
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine;
..
..
//Path for a small VS2017 solution file.
String slnPath = @"<**>\Project_2017\Project_2017.sln";
Type EnvDteType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");

object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(EnvDteType, true);
EnvDTE.DTE DteObject = (EnvDTE.DTE)obj;

EnvDTE.Solution SolutionObject = (EnvDTE.Solution)DteObject.Solution;
SolutionObject.Open(slnPath);

Projects ProjectObjects = SolutionObject.Projects;
foreach (Project project in ProjectObjects)
{
  //vcpro is NULL.
  VCProject vcpro = project.Object as VCProject;
}
```

Am I missing something here, or is it a genuine problem of VS2017?
In any case, How can we resolve this or any workaround for this?

Any help is most welcomed.
Thanks.